# Using Selenium to select a value in a React dropdown in Python?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, select, dropdown

First time using Selenium and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong

I'm trying to go to https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/vix/quote_table and click on the dropdown boxes, I am trying to select:

- Volume: Greather than 0 (Spelling error apparently)
- Options Range: All
- Expiration: All

I am able to click the dropdown boxes but I can't select the values I need. I can't seem to find the values anywhere in the HTML that I am looking for. I am struggling due to the class names that seem to change when the dropdown is clicked. There's no code like "option value = All" or anything strikingly obvious to me.

```
link = "https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/{}/quote_table".format(ticker)


driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get(link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
find = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'css-19bqh2r')))
find.click()
```

Now I am unsure what to do after this. The dropdowns all seem to have the same class name and I'm unsure how to identify the particular one I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site is kinda a pain to work with... those dropdowns especially but I finally got it to work. Basically you need to have waits on each click because the site takes a second to load and then each dropdown loads the options which takes a second, etc. You have to click the dropdown to open it and then click the desired option once it's loaded.

```
link = "https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/{}/quote_table".format(ticker)
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")
driver.get(link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
# dismiss the bottom hovering panel
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//button[text()='Read less']")))).click();

# Volume
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Volume:']/following-sibling::div")))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Volume:']/following-sibling::div//div[text()='Greather than 0']")))).click()

# Options Range
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Options Range:']/following-sibling::div")))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Options Range:']/following-sibling::div//div[text()='All']")))).click()

# Expiration
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Expiration:']/following-sibling::div")))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH("//div[text()='Expiration:']/following-sibling::div//div[text()='All']")))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to slightly tweak it in order for it to work but its great :)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Volume:']/following-sibling::div//div//div"))).click()